# Autocompletion on dynamically created input fields using jQuery and Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm trying to get an autocomplete with Typeahead on dynamically created input fields running. I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
     <a href="#" class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</a> </br>
     <div><input type="text" name="typeahead[]" class="typeahead tt-query" id="1"></div>    
     <div><input type="text" name="typeahead[]" class="typeahead tt-query" id="2"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
/***************Autocompletion***************/

                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                    name: 'typeahead',
                    remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
                    limit : 10
                    });
                });


/***************Create Input fields dynamically***************/

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
                        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
                        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
                        var x = 2; //initlal text box count

                        $(add_button).click(function(e)
                        {
                            if(x < max_fields)
                            {
                                x++; 
                                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="typeahead[]" class="typeahead tt-query" id="' + x + '"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
                            }
                        });

                        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e)
                        {
                            $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
                        })
                    });
```

I can create new input fields by clicking on the "Add More Fields" link.
The autocompletion on my 2 existing text fields are [also working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKdLl.png).
But when I create a new input field, the autocompletion is not working.
The data for the autocompletion is coming from a MYSQL database.

I hope that somebody knows why this isn't working.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new element:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e)
{
    if(x < max_fields)
    {
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="typeahead[]" 
                   class="typeahead tt-query" id="' + x + '">
                   <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});
```

you need to initialize the corresponding typeahead object. After the previous ***$(wrapper).append*** you need to add:

```
$('#' + x).typeahead({
      name: 'typeahead',
      remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
      limit : 10
});
```